# how python [0] * 3 are independent but [[0] * 3] * 3 each sub list is the same object?

Tags: python, list, memory, allocation

```
my_list = [0] * 3
my_list[0] = 1
```

outputs to
[1, 0, 0]

```
my_2ndlist = [[0] * 3] * 3
my_2ndlist[1][1] = 5
```

outputs to
[[0, 5, 0], [0, 5, 0], [0, 5, 0]]

I think I know that
x = 1
y = 1
makes x and y point to the same location in memory.
So I get the sense of the second output, even if it's not what I think you would expect.
But then I don't fully get the first as I would expect it's still 3 times a reference to the same memory location.

Any explanation that could help me understand better? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you print addresses of `my_list[0], my_list[1], my_2ndlist[0], my_2ndlist[1]` you will see that `my_list[0], my_list[1]` have 2 different addreses and `my_2ndlist[0], my_2ndlist[1]` have same addresses.

```
my_list = [0] * 3
my_list[0] = 1
print(my_list)
print(id(my_list[0]), id(my_list[1]))

my_2ndlist = [[0] * 3] * 3
my_2ndlist[1][1] = 5
print(my_2ndlist)
print(id(my_2ndlist[0]), id(my_2ndlist[1]))
```

That happens because `[0] * 3` will copy an integer object with the value zero 3 times. And in python when primitive type objects are copied they are deeply copied(integer is primitive type). But, `[[0] * 3] * 3` this will copy list `[0, 0, 0]` 3 times. Lists are not primitive type objects so they are shallow copied. Maybe [this link](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/shallow-deep-copy) will help you to understand.

Comment: thank you. at first glance, I would expect the [0] in the expression [0] * 3 to be an integer value "encapsulated" in a list, let's call it "x-list", and the expression result in x-list + x-list + x-list, therefore being treated as a list object. but I get the sense